# Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.250 : Replace sencha compile output file name "all-classes.js" with custom ones

Tags: extjs, compiler-construction, command

The `sencha compile page` command concatenates any javascript files needed by an HTML page then writes the result to a single file called "all-classes.js". I would like to replace this file name with custom ones :

```
sencha compile 
page -name=page1 -in Page1.php -out build/Page1.php and
page -name=page2 -in Page2.php -out build/Page2.php and
restore page1 and
concat -yui build/Page1.js and
restore page2 and
concat -yui build/Page2.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a simple solution as an option provided by the [`sencha compile page`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_reference-section-18) command named `--classes-file` (`-cla`) :

```
sencha compile 
page -name=page1 -cla Page1.js -in Page1.php -out build/Page1.php and
page -name=page2 -cla Page2.js -in Page2.php -out build/Page2.php and
restore page1 and
concat -yui build/Page1.js and
restore page2 and
concat -yui build/Page2.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Cheers, I am looking for the same answer. I have only a hint, not yet a best-practice.

In the .sencha/app/build-impl.xml file, exists the following target:

```
<!-- compile the page -->
<x-sencha-command>
    compile
        ${build.options}
        page
            -name=page
            -in=index.html
            -out=${build.dir}/index.html
        and
        restore
            page
        and
        ${build.operations}
        and
        concat
            ${build.compression}
            -out=${build.dir}/all-classes.js
</x-sencha-command>
```

As you see the "all-classes.js" is defined here.

I've attempted the change here, and it... worked half way. 
1) it did create the min.js file with the new name.
2) it did not update the index.html with the correct path (you have to do that)

However, this may not be best practice - as I understand - that it may not be good to maintain modifications in the build-impl.xml as this may cause complication from sencha upgrade perspective.

Maybe there could be a sencha.cfg setting? That sure would be nice.

Thank you for your question. +1. I hope others respond.
All the best!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have the file named "build-impl.xml" since my app is not generated via sencha cmd. Anyway, sencha cmd provides a simple option which does the job. Have a look at my own answer for details. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thx, i'll take a look. I find sencha cmd very flexible for scaffolding environments, and extending build. Your solution is sublime, i'll have to review. +1. All the best.